# mdadm recovery RAID1

Tags: raid1

After a yum update, I lost my server.

The problem was that the used disk for booting up was not the proper one
I have 3 disks and one of them is the one that is used for booting up the system.

After having recovered my server, my raid was lost (certainly because I tired to rebuild my grub to recover my srv). However I still see the raid that was created before. How can I recover my raid... if possible?

```
[root@max-centos tmp]# mdadm --examine  /dev/sda /dev/sdb 
/dev/sda:
          Magic : Intel Raid ISM Cfg Sig.
        Version : 1.1.00
    Orig Family : c72a928b
         Family : c72a928b
     Generation : 00055aa2
     Attributes : All supported
           UUID : c08f9cc5:91d84dd4:1ba209d0:0101a676
       Checksum : d26db931 correct
    MPB Sectors : 1
          Disks : 2
   RAID Devices : 1

  Disk00 Serial : WD-WCAZAK265780
          State : active
             Id : 00000000
    Usable Size : 1953519616 (931.51 GiB 1000.20 GB)

[myraid]:
           UUID : 84f26dd7:ab627e7d:e11e4043:93753db1
     RAID Level : 1
        Members : 2
          Slots : [UU]
    Failed disk : none
      This Slot : 0
    Sector Size : 512
     Array Size : 1953519616 (931.51 GiB 1000.20 GB)
   Per Dev Size : 1953519880 (931.51 GiB 1000.20 GB)
  Sector Offset : 0
    Num Stripes : 7630936
     Chunk Size : 64 KiB
       Reserved : 0
  Migrate State : idle
      Map State : normal
    Dirty State : clean
     RWH Policy : off

  Disk01 Serial : WD-WCAZAK273297
          State : active
             Id : 00000001
    Usable Size : 1953519616 (931.51 GiB 1000.20 GB)
/dev/sdb:
          Magic : Intel Raid ISM Cfg Sig.
        Version : 1.1.00
    Orig Family : c72a928b
         Family : c72a928b
     Generation : 00055aa2
     Attributes : All supported
           UUID : c08f9cc5:91d84dd4:1ba209d0:0101a676
       Checksum : d26db931 correct
    MPB Sectors : 1
          Disks : 2
   RAID Devices : 1

  Disk01 Serial : WD-WCAZAK273297
          State : active
             Id : 00000001
    Usable Size : 1953519616 (931.51 GiB 1000.20 GB)

[myraid]:
           UUID : 84f26dd7:ab627e7d:e11e4043:93753db1
     RAID Level : 1
        Members : 2
          Slots : [UU]
    Failed disk : none
      This Slot : 1
    Sector Size : 512
     Array Size : 1953519616 (931.51 GiB 1000.20 GB)
   Per Dev Size : 1953519880 (931.51 GiB 1000.20 GB)
  Sector Offset : 0
    Num Stripes : 7630936
     Chunk Size : 64 KiB
       Reserved : 0
  Migrate State : idle
      Map State : normal
    Dirty State : clean
     RWH Policy : off

  Disk00 Serial : WD-WCAZAK265780
          State : active
             Id : 00000000
    Usable Size : 1953519616 (931.51 GiB 1000.20 GB)
```

-

```
[root@max-centos tmp]# lsblk
NAME              MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                 8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
sdb                 8:16   0 931.5G  0 disk 
sdc                 8:32   0 232.9G  0 disk 
\u251c\u2500sdc1              8:33   0     1G  0 part /boot
\u2514\u2500sdc2              8:34   0 231.9G  0 part 
  \u251c\u2500centos01-root 253:0    0    50G  0 lvm  /
  \u251c\u2500centos01-swap 253:1    0   7.8G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  \u2514\u2500centos01-home 253:2    0 174.1G  0 lvm  /home
sr0                11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```